# Unnesting an array of arrays, to a simple array in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

This doesn't work:

```
DO
$do$
    DECLARE
        nested   varchar[][] := '{{a},{b},{c}}';
        unnested varchar[];
    BEGIN    
        unnested := unnest(nested)::text[];
    END
$do$;
```

Because, it seems, the unnest expression returns a table. The error message is:

> [22P02] ERROR: malformed array literal: "a" Detail: Array value must
> start with "{" or dimension information. Where: SQL statement "SELECT
> unnest(nested)::text[]" PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 7 at
> assignment

So I guess the solution is to create an array out of the unnest return value? How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast the result of a set returning function to an array.

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
  nested   varchar[][] := '{{a},{b},{c}}';
  unnested varchar[];
BEGIN    
  unnested := array(select * from unnest(nested));
END
$do$;
```